# Is it possible to save numbers in a database when we select names

Tags: php, oracle

I am working on a database/php project. 
There are three tables in the database... one has roleId and role.. second one has userId and username... so there is a dropdown of username and role from both these tables.. when a user makes a selection, the data should be saved in the third table which has roleId and userId.

```
Table1 : roleId, role
Table2: userId, username
Table3: roleId, userId
```

How it can be done?

This is what I have tried so far...

```
<?php

require_once './queries.php';
$roleId = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "roleId");
$userId= filter_input(INPUT_POST, "userId");
$addname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "addname");
$addrole = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "addrole");
$deletename = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "deletename");
$deleterole = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "deleterole");
$switch = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "switch");

switch ($switch) {
case 'add':
            echo Queries::addRole($roleId, $role);
            break;

}
?>
```

queries.php

```
public static function addRole($userId, $roleId) {
       $dbUser = "";
       $dbPass = "";
        $dbConn = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=)(PORT=))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=)))";  
        $conn = oci_connect($dbUser, $dbPass, $dbConn);
        $sql = oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO ROLE (roleId, userId) VALUES (:roleid, :userId)");
        oci_bind_by_name($sql,':roleId', $roleId);
        oci_bind_by_name($sql,':userId', $userId);
        oci_execute($sql);

    }
```

.js

```
$("#selectrole").submit(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'functions/role-functions.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {"roleId": $('#roleId').val(),"userId": $('#userId').val(),  "switch": "add"},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {
            $('#selectdept').trigger('reset');
            $("#userId").val('').trigger('change');
            resultAlert('#adminResult', '#resultAdminContent', '<strong>You data was succefully saved!</strong>', 'alert-success');
        }, error: function () {
            resultAlert('#adminResult', '#resultAdminContent', '<strong>Error! Your data was not saved!</strong>', 'alert-danger');
        }
    });
});
```

form

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
    <div id="selectrole" class="hide" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <div id="resultActivityContent"></div>
    </div>  
    <form class="cmxform" id="addroles">
        <legend>Add Roles</legend>
        <label for="names">Select Name</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="names" id="names">
           <option selected disabled></option>
           <?php 
           $dbUser = "";
            $dbPass = "";
            $dbConn = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=  )(PORT=  ))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=  )))"; 
            $conn = oci_connect($dbUser, $dbPass, $dbConn);
            $sql = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT USER.USERNAME  FROM USER");
            oci_execute($sql, OCI_DEFAULT);
            ?>
           <?php
              while (oci_fetch($sql))
                  { ?>
                echo '<option value="<?php echo oci_result($sql, 'USERNAME')?>"><?=oci_result($sql,'USERNAME') ?></option>  
            <?php   
        }?>
        </select>   
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="role">Select Role</label>
         <select class="form-control" name="role" id="role">
           <option selected disabled></option>
           <?php 
           $dbUser = "  ";
            $dbPass = "  ";
            $dbConn = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=  )(PORT=  ))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=  )))"; 
            $conn = oci_connect($dbUser, $dbPass, $dbConn);
            $sql = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT USERROLE.ROLED FROM USERROLE");
            oci_execute($sql, OCI_DEFAULT);
            ?>
           <?php
              while (oci_fetch($sql))
                  { ?>
                echo '<option value="<?php echo oci_result($sql, 'ROLE')?>"><?=oci_result($sql,'ROLE') ?></option>  
            <?php   
        }?>

        </select> 
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-primary" type="submit">Add Role</button>
        <br>
        <br>
    </form>
            </div>
     </div>       
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Answering your title: Yes.

Comment: *psssst - auto-incrementing primary key on the user table*

Comment: @MarcM updated the question.

Comment: @Script47 can you explain.. how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
I am not a PHP developer but, I am thinking that the action to save(INSERT) values in 3rd table will be triggered by an action from the form.

If so, you should select the `roleId` and `userId`, based on the `role` and `username`, into 2 variables (for example: `v_roleId` and `v_userId`) and then, perform the `INSERT into` the 3rd table with these 2 variables.

If not, please provide us more details, code parts, everything you tried ...

Comment: Ok. let me post the form as well. When i submit the values.. the error says. cannot insert NULL values into role(roleId, userId)

Comment: In your AddRole function, you have it defined as `addRole(userId, $roleId)`. The `userId` should not be `$userId` as it is `%RoleId`?

Comment: yeah.. changed it thanks.. but getting the same error

Comment: You need to do value="roleIdHere" in your select options for a value to be sent. It looks like you're doing that. Is oci_result() working for you?

Comment: Yaa it is... the error is on the oci_execute()  line.